# cuando intento registrarme me marca un error PHP Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el código completo:

```
$host = "localhost";
$puerto = "3306";
$usuario = "Ivania";
$contrasena = "tnivania#1";

  $conectar=@mysqli_connect($host,$puerto,$usuario,$contrasena);

  if (!$conectar) {
    echo "Error de conexion con el host";

      }else{
        $database='dbTecnoneed';
     $Base=mysqli_select_db($conectar, $database);

    if (!$Base) {
      echo "Base de datos no localizada";
    }
  }
  $Nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
  $Apellidos=$_POST['Apellidos'];
  $Correo=$_POST['Correo'];
  $Contrasena=$_POST['Contrasena'];

  $sql="INSERT INTO registro VALUES('$Nombre','$Apellidos','$Correo','$Contrasena')";

  $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
  
  if (!$ejecutar) 
  {
    echo "Upps!!! algo salio mal error al enviar los datos<br><href='index.html'>REGRESAR<a>";
  }else{
    echo "Tus datos fueron guardados con exito!!!<br><ahref='Pag_IP/index.html'>continuar<a>";
  }
```

Necesito ayuda, ya lo intente corregir varias veces y no puedo hacer que funcione.

> America/Mexico_City] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1
> to be mysqli, boolean given in
> /home4/Formulario_FIS/FormularioR/Registro.php on line 32

Comment: Sustituye tu `if(!$conectar)` por una estructura como la mostrada en la documentación en el apartado que dice: *estilo por procedimientos*: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php para saber exactamente que error tiene tu consulta

Comment: Por cierto no uses @ al inicio de tus métodos de conexión para silenciar los errores, además el puerto debe ser un número y no un string, como se indica en la documentación: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: He modificado la pregunta, No es necesario el uso de mayúsculas. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

En tu código hay varias cosas que deberías considerar, las señalo brevemente:

1. Replantea el orden lógico en que vas incluyendo los recursos. Por ejemplo, la conexión suele ser algo costoso, por tanto, antes de usarla, verifica que no la usarás en vano. Cuando se trata de datos posteados, verifica primeramente que esos datos existen (el usuario pudo no haber rellanado algún dato en el formulario). Si tú pasas a conectar sin más, puedes que estés conectando para nada.
2. Verifica siempre con un ternario que los datos existen antes de usarlos, de lo contrario podrás tener constantemente situaciones de *`Undefined index`*
3. El uso de `@` en el código es una mala práctica. Silencia los errores y dificulta la depuración. Programar controlando los errores debería ser prioridad en nuestros programas. Programar ignorando los errores es algo así como que un paciente se esté muriendo y el médico mire para otro lado en vez de tratar de salvarlo.
4. Estás pasando mal los parámetros a `mysqli_connect`. [Revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php) y el orden en que deben ir los parámetros. De hecho, en `mysqli` no necesitas seleccionar la base de datos a posteriori, puedes indicar a qué base de datos quieres conectar (4º parámetro), y si quieres indicar le puerto, lo puedes pasar como 5º parámetro, o ponerlo seguido de dos puntos en el host.
5. Te recomiendo que uses INSERTs explícitos, o sea, que nombres **cada columna** explícitamente en la instrucción. Si mañana tu tabla evoluciona (se le agrega una nueva columna por ejemplo que no admite nulos), tendrás código erróneo, porque el INSERT implícito no encajará.
6. Finalmente, he optado por un estilo de código donde se recogen los mensajes en una variable `$msg` la cual se imprime al final. Esto permite un mejor control en el flujo y facilita la depuración.

Intenta de este modo. Si no funciona, dime qué mensaje imprime y podremos modificarlo ligeramente para incluir mensajes de error internos que faciliten la depuración (no lo he hecho aquí porque no es recomendable mostrar en pantalla mensajes internos, que los hackers aprovecharían para vulnerar tu sistema).

```
<?php
  /*
    Primero recuperamos los datos y verificamos si no están vacíos 
    para no conectar sin necesidad ...
    La conexión es un evento costoso 
  */
  $Nombre=!empty($_POST['Nombre']) ? $_POST['Nombre'] : NULL;
  $Apellidos=!empty($_POST['Apellidos']) ? $_POST['Apellidos'] : NULL;
  $Correo=!empty($_POST['Correo']) ? $_POST['Correo'] : NULL;
  $Contrasena=!empty($_POST['Contrasena']) ? $_POST['Contrasena'] : NULL;

  if ($Nombre && $Apellidos && $Correo && $Contrasena) 
  {
    $host = "localhost";
    $usuario = "Ivania";
    $password = "tnivania#1";
    $database='dbTecnoneed';
    $puerto = "3306";

    /*
      En primer lugar, evita el uso de @, dificulta la depuración
      Luego, revisa la documentación, estás pasando mal los parámetros
        el puerto va en 5º parámetro, o lo puedes poner en el host seguido de dos puntos
        "localhost:3306". 
        El 4º parámetro es para la base de datos, de hecho en mysqli no hace falta
        usar mysqli_select_db inicialmente para conectar 
    */
    $conectar=mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$password,$database,$puerto);
    if (!$conectar) 
    {
        $msg="Error de conexion con el host";
    } else {
      /*
        Te recomiendo que uses INSERTs explícitos
        Es decir, que nombres cada columna en el INSERT 
      */
      $sql="INSERT INTO registro VALUES('$Nombre','$Apellidos','$Correo','$Contrasena')";
      $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
      if (!$ejecutar) 
      {
        $msg="Upps!!! algo salio mal error al enviar los datos<br><href='index.html'>REGRESAR<a>";
      } else {
        $msg="Tus datos fueron guardados con exito!!!<br><ahref='Pag_IP/index.html'>continuar<a>";
      }
    }
  } else {
    $msg="Revisa los datos del POST";
  }
  echo $msg;
?>
```